# Unexpected Exception While generataing endpoint library in eclipse

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I developed my web application in google app engine and generated end point library.but today I can not generate end point library.
showing popup window Exception(Generating cloud endpoint has encountred errors and is not compelete)
Exception is:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createClientLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:104)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:212)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:475)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:507)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)

Caused by: com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1050)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.postRequest(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:53)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.generateClientLib(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:44)
    ... 41 more
Root exception:
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1050)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.postRequest(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:53)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.generateClientLib(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createClientLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:104)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:212)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:475)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:507)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: Do you import any package that has been named as **repackaged**?

Comment: no. Actually it was worked on last week but today when I try to generate endpoint that time it gives above exception.

Comment: Could you post your endpoint class?

Comment: I have more than 10 endpoint classes.so its not possible to post endpoint classes.

Comment: Can you `Window->Show View-> Error log` and see (while you regenerate the endpoint libraries) to see if anything shows up there?

Comment: Also I tried to create new project in my eclipse then also it gives same exception at generating cloud endpoint.

Comment: I have posted above exception from error log.

Comment: This is probably due to a **bad method signature** or an annotation problem. Maybe if you tried commenting out a method you recently added... I was facing the same issues when I added a method that e.g returned a primitive (not allowed). From a quick google search that seems to be a bug on GAE. What version of GAE sdk are you using?

Comment: appengine-java-sdk-1.8.3. so how to resolve this issue. Means Creating New end point classes and generating cloud endpoint library?

Answer (score 1):

Answering By Me:
Change eclipse setup.
Means replace the eclipse,plugins newly etc,